# How do I make a backup of the entire ZFS pool (zroot that's created during FreeBSD installation)?

Tags: freebsd, zfs

as above.

when I mentioned snapshot, I meant all of the pool and not just the individual filesystem created by FreeBSD. So in case I made a mess in various folders, I can just rollback to this snapshot and my FreeBSD instance feels it's newly installed/factory reset.

Thanks

---

for reference, here are the various filesystems created during Auto-ZFS installation

```
root@mydesktop:/home/myuser # zfs list
NAME                 USED  AVAIL  REFER  MOUNTPOINT
zroot                887M  51.0G    96K  /zroot
zroot/ROOT           884M  51.0G    96K  none
zroot/ROOT/default   884M  51.0G   884M  /
zroot/tmp            112K  51.0G   112K  /tmp
zroot/usr            432K  51.0G    96K  /usr
zroot/usr/home       144K  51.0G   144K  /usr/home
zroot/usr/ports       96K  51.0G    96K  /usr/ports
zroot/usr/src         96K  51.0G    96K  /usr/src
zroot/var            724K  51.0G    96K  /var
zroot/var/audit       96K  51.0G    96K  /var/audit
zroot/var/crash       96K  51.0G    96K  /var/crash
zroot/var/log        244K  51.0G   244K  /var/log
zroot/var/mail        96K  51.0G    96K  /var/mail
zroot/var/tmp         96K  51.0G    96K  /var/tmp
```

Answer (score 0):

Unless you want to make a block-level backup of each vdev in the pool (e.g. using `dd`), ZFS only provides you with a dataset-level backup mechanism. However, you can create [recursive snapshots](https://docs.oracle.com/cd/E19253-01/819-5461/gdfdt/index.html) and back these up using [`zfs send`](https://openzfs.github.io/openzfs-docs/man/8/zfs-send.8.html) using the `-R` option. This way you can back up all datasets in your zpool.